# Android: I want to sort a database by timer, but the timer is in the database as a string

Tags: java, android, sql

I have a score and a timer. Both are put into a database, and I'd like to fetch the score and timer in an descending and ascending way respectively. However, my timer is currently put into my database as a string. How can I still sort my database by my score and timer?

Here's my code:

Timer.java

```
mEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
mTotalTime = mEndTime - mStartTime;
int seconds = (int) (mTotalTime / 1000);
int minutes = seconds / 60;
seconds = seconds % 60;
int millis = (int) mTotalTime % 1000;
String time = String.format("%02d:%02d.%03d", minutes, seconds, millis);
```

Database query

```
Cursor c = db.query(TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, TableInfo.LB_SCORE + " DESC, " + TableInfo.LB_TIME + " ASC", "5");
```

I think maybe I could add three more columns for minutes, seconds, and milliseconds and sort by each, but that seems like more work than necessary.

Comment: why can't you sort Strings?

Comment: I try that in my code above and it doesn't work. Also I think strings sort "13" before "2".

Comment: maybe you should insert your timer as `02` and `13`

Comment: yes, he is right string would not sorted in digit order, one alternative way to sort this, split your time in three column, one for hour one four minute and another for second, then sort three of them but first second then minute and then hour, it will works.

Comment: Would that look like this when I sort?

Cursor c = db.query(TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, TableInfo.LB_SCORE + " DESC, " + TableInfo.LB_minute + " ASC", + TableInfo.LB_second + " ASC",+ TableInfo.LB_second + " ASC","5");

Comment: If your minutes will *never* exceed 99, then the format `"%02d:%02d.%03d"` ensures a string value that can be sorted directly, as a VARCHAR. E.g. 3 seconds vs 1 hour: `'00:03.000' < '60:00.000'` (as SQL literals).

Comment: @Andreas yeah my minutes will never exceed 99. So you're saying change the data type to VARCHAR and it should work? I'll try it

Comment: @Andreas, that works thanks!